# Using `Limit` with the Option `Assumptions`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate the following limit

$$L=\lim_{r \to 0} \left( 1 + r \frac{El^{'}(r)}{El(r)} \right)$$

by letting *Mathematica* to know

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{El^{'}(r)}{El(r)} = A $$

where $A$ is a constant. It is evident that we should have $L=1$.

I used the following

```
Limit[1 + (r Derivative[1][El][r])/El[r], r -> 0, 
Assumptions -> {Limit[Derivative[1][El][r]/El[r], r -> 0] == a}]
```

But it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe replace that quotient by (A+O[r])?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume analyticity :

```
Limit[1 + (r El'[r])/El[r], r -> 0, Analytic -> True]

(*  1  *)
```

`Analytic->True` assumes that generic functions (e.g., `El[r]` and `El'[r]` in this case) are [analytic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticFunction.html).

Comment: Can you kindly add some explanations that what the option Analytic really does, in your answer? :)

Comment: @H.R. - See edit. If you need any more you will need to talk to a mathematician.

Comment: That seems fine. Thank you. So by turning this option on, *Mathematica* understands that $\frac{El^{'}(r)}{El(r)}$ is analytic and hence its limit equals the value of the function? right?

Comment: @H.R. - "... you will need to talk to a mathematician"

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what was suggested by @BobHanlon, one might just replace the quotient of `El'[r])/El[r]` by the assumed value of `A+O[r]` to denote that it is the given constant `A` to first order.

```
In[646]:= Limit[1 + r (A + O[r]), r -> 0]

(* Out[646]= 1 *)
```